# Error when trying to add coordinates of pixels after using sampleRegions function

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to extract a stacked ee.Image()using sampleRegions. The first step is running without any issues. However after running sampleRegions, I want to add coordinates.

```
var dem_30m = ee.Image('projects/isdasoil/covariates/dem_30m');
var dem_100m = ee.Image('projects/isdasoil/covariates/dem_100m');
var landcover_100m = ee.Image('projects/isdasoil/covariates/landcover_100m');
var landcover_30m = ee.Image('projects/isdasoil/covariates/landcover_30m');
var landsat7_2000 = ee.Image('projects/isdasoil/covariates/landsat7_2000');
var landsat8_2015 = ee.Image('projects/isdasoil/covariates/landsat8_2015');
var landsat8_2018 = ee.Image('projects/isdasoil/covariates/landsat8_2018');
var sentinal2_l2a_s1 = ee.Image('projects/isdasoil/covariates/sentinel2_l2a_s1');
var sentinel2_l2a_s2 = ee.Image('projects/isdasoil/covariates/sentinel2_l2a_s2');
var surface_water = ee.Image('projects/isdasoil/covariates/surface_water');

var stack = dem_30m
  .addBands(dem_100m)
  .addBands(landcover_100m)
  .addBands(landcover_30m)
  .addBands(landsat7_2000)
  .addBands(landsat8_2015)
  .addBands(landsat8_2018)
  .addBands(sentinal2_l2a_s1)
  .addBands(sentinel2_l2a_s2)
  .addBands(surface_water);

// Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
var collection = stack.sampleRegions({
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  collection: table,
  // Keep this list of properties from the polygons.
  properties: ['farm_id', 'T_Year'],
  // Set the farm to get Landsat pixels in the polygons.
  scale: 30
});
```

I receive the following error when running collection_with_latlon:

```
FeatureCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=00000000000000000000_2):
List.get: List is empty (index is 1).
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

```
// Break point coordinates up into properties (table columns) explicitly.
var collection_with_latlon = collection.map(function (feature) {
  var coordinates = feature.geometry().transform('epsg:4326').coordinates();
  return feature.set('lon', coordinates.get(0), 'lat', coordinates.get(1));
});

print(collection_with_latlon);

Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: collection_with_latlon,
    description: 'hist_tx',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't turn on the `geometries` option in sampleRegions, then the results don't have a geometry.  From the docs:

> geometries (Boolean, default: false):
>
> If true, the results will include a point geometry per sampled pixel. Otherwise, geometries will be omitted (saving memory).